# Angular $scope not binding to view after update, navigation and $scope.$apply()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a database holding a list. I have a form which adds a row to the database list via a `factory`. Once the row is added, the server sends back the updated list. Using the `$q.defer().promise` returned by the `$http.post`, I update the list on the `$scope` within the `controller` with the updated list upon `defer.resolve`.

Whilst testing, I have come across an anomoly. My issue is that if I navigate away from the `view` which has the `controller` performing the update and back to the `view` before the update has completed, when the update completes, the `$scope` is not updated with the updated list - well, it's not updated in the `view` anyway. If I navigate away (within the SPA), and then back again, I get the correct data.

The `factory` which does the update returns a `promise` from the `post` within it's `setData` function. When the promise resolves, the `$scope` is updated.

This is the code in the `controller` waiting patiently for the `$http.post` to resolve:

```
  promise.then(function() {
    $scope.people = dataService.getData();
    $scope.newperson = '';
    $scope.submitting = false;
    $scope.$apply();
  });
```

This is the html in the corresponding view which should bind seemlessly with `$scope.people`:

```
<li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="person in people">{{person.firstName}} {{person.lastName}}</li>
```

I have mimicked a slow server response (using setTimeout) in this JSBin: https://jsbin.com/hihazegosi/1/edit?js,console,output

**TO RECREATE ISSUE:**

1. Navigate to `People`
2. Add a person. See in console that post is called.
3. Navigate to `Home` and back to `People` within 5 seconds.
4. Wait on people, and notice in the console that person should have been added to the scope.
5. If you navigate to `Home` and straight back to `People`, you'll see that the model has been updated.

Note, if you a) navigate back to `People` after the post is complete, you will see the correct data. If you b) stay on `People`, you will see the correct data. `$scope.$apply()` is called without checking `$scope.$$phase` as this returns `'$digest'` in all cases, so you'll see an error in scenario b.

Could anyone explain what is happening here, and if there is a way of getting the `$scope` and `view` to stay in sync in this scenario?

Comment: A minor note on your code: you can use `$timeout` instead of `setTimeout` and then you don't need to do `$scope.apply()`

Comment: I would normally, but if I did that, in this case, I wouldn't be mimicking an asynchronous post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe what is happening is this:

- When you navigate away from the people state the controller and its scope is destroyed
- So when the `dataService.setData` promise resolves, the `$scope` it has is not referring to the scope of the people controller (it is referring to the old controller from before you navigated away)
- When you then switch to home and back to people afterwards, the people controller is recreated again, and in its constructor it does `dataService.getData` which then fills its `$scope.people` with the correct values

I think you will need to store the list of people somewhere that persists across state changes, e.g. in the `dataService` service

You could also use `$broadcast` to pass a message to the controller whenever it needs updating. You can do this like so:

- When `dataService.setData` resolves do `$rootScope.$broadcast('peopleUpdated')` - this will send a message from the root scope down through all scopes in your app
- Listen for this event in your controller with `$scope.$on('peopleUpdated', function() { $scope.people = dataService.getData(); })`

Comment: the data are already in the dataService, the problem as you said is that the dataService.getData(); in the promise resolution that is referring to the old scope

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't help as the data in all scopes is coming from the `dataService`. If this is an "old scope / new scope issue", how can the new scope get notified of a change in the `dataService`?

Comment: what I mean is that you could store the list of people in a service and reference that from the html like `<li ng-repeat="person in dataService.get()"></li>` (where `.get` is returning a list saved on the service, not doing a web call of course!)

Comment: You of course cannot get a reference to the correct scope object at the time you make the promise function, as it hasn't been created yet. Perhaps you can find a way to stop the controller being created/destroyed by ui-router?

Comment: Or perhaps you can broadcast an event from the `$rootScope`

Comment: @Mike You clearly have the correct reason for why this is happening, but I'm looking for a solution. I just tried `person in dataService.getData()` and get nothing. How might an event broadcast from the `$rootScope` work in this case?

Comment: @dewd you can do `$rootScope.$broadcast('peopleUpdated')` and then in the people controller you can listen for this event with `$scope.$on('peopleUpdated', function() { $scope.people = dataService.getData(); })`

Comment: Indeed, I can. It works. Could you edit your answer and add this as the solution? If you do that, I'll accept it. I might even give you a +1. :)